# Softfail on forwarded emails sent through Yahoo mail - Is there a fix?

Tags: spf, dmarc, domainkeys

happy to be here.

Excuse me for the wall of text but I am trying to help a friend who wants to keep on using his Yahoo mail for sending emails from his business email address.

His mail server is on cPanel with shared IP address 212.16.186.119 and we are basically forwarding all incoming email from his domain to his personal Yahoo email account. We then set up a "Send mail as" address inside Yahoo mail to send emails.

So the path is:

1. Email sent to the business email address goes to cPanel's email inbox
2. Email is automatically forwarded to personal Yahoo mailbox
3. Reply email is sent through Yahoo servers using the "Send mail as" option

I have SPF configured although I don't know if it is configured correctly where I have added two of Yahoo's IPs that I found in flagged messages but this is not working consistently as Yahoo uses many IP addresses for outgoing email.

The problem here is that Yahoo does not have an SPF record that I can use and include in my SPF and DomainKeys is replaced with DKIM in cPanel. I have also added a DMARC record to see if it will help (passes all tests in MX Toolbox) but the emails keep getting marked as spam.

Most messages get a softfail flag. **domain of transitioning info@exampledomain.com does not designate 98.137.69.146 as permitted sender**

Is the above information enough for someone to understand how (and if) this can be resolved?
Your help and insights will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: SPF and email forwarding doesn’t work well together

Comment: The IP address solution cannot work because there are too many IP addresses to put in a single record. Instead, try adding `include=yahoo.com` to the SPF record.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and recommendations.

Comment: I added the `include:yahoo.com` in the SPF record and while some emails went through to some mailboxes, some other (especially Microsoft's) keep on flagging it. Here is a header excerpt from a personal MS email `Authentication-Results: spf=temperror (sender IP is 98.137.68.30) smtp.mailfrom=domain.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified) header.d=yahoo.com;dmarc=temperror action=none header.from=domain.com Received-SPF: TempError (protection.outlook.com: error in processing during lookup of domain.com: DNS Timeout)` Also, MX Toolbox gives a warning of too many included DNS lookups. Ideas?